# Create paperclip attachment from rmagick image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, rmagick

I have a problem to find a way to save an image created with RMagick in a paperclip attachment.

```
imageList = Magick::ImageList.new
imageList.new("images/apple.gif", "images/overlay.png")
...
picture = imageList.flatten_images
```

I am in a model that have an attached file

`has_attached_file :picture,
    :url => ...,
    :path => ...`

and i just want my image returned by imageList.flatten_images to be saved as the picture of my model.

Does anyone know how to do it easily please?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's see if that's what you need

```
picture = imageList.flatten_images
file = Tempfile.new('my_picture.jpg')
picture.write(file.path)
YourModel.create(:picture => file, ...)
```

Change `YourModel` with the model you are using...

Comment: I had to change the my_picture to end with .jpg for the processing to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should force the extension on TempFile.new; in this case I pull the original image from S3 or some such, this is happening in the model of course:

```
orig_img = Magick::ImageList.new(self.photo.url(:original))

#process image here

# Force extension with array form:
file = Tempfile.new(['processed','.jpg'])
orig_img.write(file.path)
self.photo = file
self.save
```

Answer (score 0):

In the later versions of Paperclip (mine is `5.0.0`), you'll need to provide Paperclip's own `Tempfile` instance:

```
file = Paperclip::Tempfile.new(["processed", ".jpg"])
thumb.write(file.path)
result = YourModel.create(image: file)
```

This preserves the file extension at the end of the filename, so that it is recognized by Paperclip when it's uploaded.