# How to create an RMagick image from a Paperclip attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, file-io, paperclip, rmagick

Suppose I've got an image stored as a paperclip attachment. I want to use this image in RMagick to compose other images. But when I ask paperclip about it, I'm handed a URL which hands back the image data; and I guess I could read this into a file, and then read the file back into RMagick -- and in fact, that's what I'm planning on doing for now -- but it seems like there very well ought to be a more direct way.

In other words, my question is the inverse of this one: [how to create a Paperclip attachment from an 
RMagick image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035212/create-paperclip-attachment-from-rmagick-image) I want to know the most direct means of creating an RMagick image from a Paperclip-attached picture.

UPDATE: Just in case it wasn't clear -- the basic problem is that ImageList.new() won't accept the path because paperclip hands back a URL and RMagick is apparently expecting a local filesystem path. Perhaps I'm missing something here, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Ruby. Monkey-patch `Paperclip::Attachment`!

```
# lib/paperclip_magick.rb
require 'RMagick'

module PaperclipMagick
  def to_rmagick(style_name = default_style)
     @image_list ||= ImageList.new(self.path(style_name))
  end
end

Paperclip::Attachment.send(:include, Magick)
Paperclip::Attachment.send(:include, PaperclipMagick)
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear from the question -- the problem is that ImageList.new() won't accept the path because it's a URL and it's expecting a local filesystem path. Perhaps I'm missing something here, though.

Comment: Hm. `Attachment#path` should be returning the local filesystem path, not the URL. Can you post some sample code?

Comment: This was it, I wasn't using the API properly. Serves me right -- thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that since you are operating on you the attachment in you model (I guess its an Image model? Lets call it that..) you should add methods to your image model to do what ever operations you need to do eg.

```
class image < A::B


 def add_logo

   add logo to  self.attachment.path

 end 

end
```